# With open() statement with Naive Bayes Classifier takes to long

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes

I have a csv file with 3483 lines and 460K characters and 65K words, and I'm trying to use this corpus to train a NaiveBayes classifier in Scikit-learn.

The problem is when I use this statement below, takes too long (1 hour and did not finish).

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier 
import csv 

with open('train.csv', 'r') as fp:
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="csv")
```

Any guesses of what I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your CSV file formatted like so : http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/classifiers.html

Comment: Yes @vendaTrout

This is an example of the file:

```instagrama,INSTAGRAM
#fb,FACEBOOK
facebookio,FACEBOOK
facebooktime messenger iphone,FACEBOOK
whatsapp com,WHATSSUP
facebooko    #fb,FACEBOOK
facebookiokio  #fb,FACEBOOK
instagramas:  ,INSTAGRAM
facebook   https:fb,FACEBOOK
facebook  #fb,FACEBOOK```

Comment: Assuming, each train data and label is separated by a "\n", can you profile the function for a smaller csv, or this. Please have a look at the stdlib [profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) module.

Comment: I made a small csv with 200 lines and it takes 3 minutes to load.How can I profile this?

Comment: I am also facing this issue but no luck, any alternative for same work ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with this lib.

It's documented in the following links:

https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/pull/136

https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/issues/77

Small story: The library do not deals well with large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure of the text blob library but perhaps this may help-

I had written the following code to train a multinomial naive bayes model with raw textual data after vectorizing and transforming the text in my dataset.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

#import dataset
url = ("C:\\Users\\sidharth.m\\Desktop\\Project_sid_35352\\Final.csv")
documents = pd.read_csv(url)

array = documents.values

x = array[0:, 1]

y= array[0:, 0]


count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(x)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)

model=MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_tfidf, y)

predicted = model.predict(X_train_tfidf)

acc = accuracy_score(y, predicted)
print(acc)
```